# How can I use an external library in a react native module

Tags: react-native

I am creating a react native library using [this library](https://github.com/brodybits/create-react-native-module), but my issue is how to add an external library (e.g `library.framework`) into it.

When I drag the library to a normal application project I see the library added to Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded content under the "General tab" and I am able to use it perfectly.

[Image - using the library in a normal application project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1ahC.jpg)

But when I create an react native module and try to use the library I created it the `created-react-library > ios`. The is no general tab, hence the library cannot be accessed.

[Image - using the library in a react native create module > ios project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qazma.jpg)

what is the proper way of using an external library in a react-native-create-library module?

Answer (score -1):

You need to select a target under your project, to see the general tab.

[image]

Comment: seems like you dont understand my question fully. Have you created a react-native-module before?